# Firebase Firestore - Displaying Queried Data in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native

I require some help that I couldn't find easily in the documentation.

So I've gotten my head around how to create a document in firebase on signup and setting the doc's ID to the current users uid. Now I want to reference the current user's doc and use its data throughout screens.

This is the function I use to retrieve the data:

```
const user = auth.currentUser;
const GettingUserData = async() => {
        const userData = firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
        const doc = await userData.get();
        if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
        } else {
        console.log('User data:', doc.data());
    }
  }
```

how would I go about using the data inside of **doc.data()** in something like `<Text>`{data.displayName}`</Text>`

Help or a link to read through would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage remote data, you need a state to store that information.

If you are using a functional component:

```
const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState(null)

const user = auth.currentUser;
const GettingUserData = async() => {
        const userData = firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
        const doc = await userData.get();
        if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
        } else {
        console.log('User data:', doc.data());
        setUserData(doc.data)
    }
  }
  
  
  return (<View><Text>{userData?.name}</Text></View>)
```

if you are using class components:

```
const user = auth.currentUser;
const GettingUserData = async() => {
        const userData = firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
        const doc = await userData.get();
        if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No such document!');
        } else {
        console.log('User data:', doc.data());
        this.setState({userData: doc.data()})
    }
  }
  
  
  return (<View><Text>{this.state.userData?.name}</Text></View>)
```

Comment: Great thanks @franceco - Helped me get my data in and using it throughout